# Difference between '-keep class a.b.**' and '-keep class a.b.** {}'

Tags: android, proguard

I saw some proguard config have lines like:

```
-keep class a.b.** {}
```

I am confused about the use of `{}`.
I know that

`-keep class a.b.**` means keep all class name in package `a.b` and its sub-packages.

`-keep class a.b.** {*;}` means keep all class name and class methods/fields in package `a.b` and its sub-packages.

But the the use of `-keep class a.b.** {}`?

Answer (score 0):

Empty curly braces don't have any effect. Sometimes, pasted configuration on blogs contains something like

```
-keep class a.b.** { <methods>; }
```

If the blogging software treats the angle brackets as html, it is erroneously displayed as

```
-keep class a.b.** { ; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I saw were some local proguard config file, not text on web page, and the braces were empty. So in your opinion, `-keep class a.b.** {}` is the same as `-keep class a.b.**`?

Comment: @Patrice Yes, they are the same. I'm the developer of ProGuard, so I'm pretty sure.